# ActivityWatcher & ProcessObserver

Tags: android, android-framework

I would like to know the purpose of foloowing two files:

frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/IActivityWatcher.aidl
[description: Callback interface to watch the user's traversal through activities.]

frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/IProcessObserver.aidl
[no description]

I am trying to build an app wherein user can decide which apps can be run during particular period of time (say, from 10am till 4pm).
Is there any way where my app will get notified if one the apps specified by the user starts? This way my app can send kill command (I am assuming that root access is available.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `IActivityWatcher` has been removed beginning with JellyBean, in order to monitor which `Activity` is running foreground, you can use `IProcessObserver` as following:

```
mActivityManagerNative = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault();
if (mActivityManagerNative != null) {
    try {
        mActivityManagerNative.registerProcessObserver(mProcessObserver);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "onCreate() RemoteException!");
    }
 }

private IProcessObserver.Stub mProcessObserver = new IProcessObserver.Stub() {
    @Override
    public void onForegroundActivitiesChanged(int pid, int uid, boolean foregroundActivities) {
       doWhatUWantHere();
    }

    @Override
    public void onImportanceChanged(int pid, int uid, int importance) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessDied(int pid, int uid) {
    }
};
```

P.S.
You can use following code snippets to get the package name of foreground running Activity:

```
private String getForegroundPackage() {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RecentTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRecentTasks(1,
            ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
    return taskInfo.isEmpty()
            ? null : taskInfo.get(0).baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
}
```

Comment: FYI, I tried to use reflection to call ```registerProcessObserver``` but this method requires ```android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER``` which is removed in android 4.4